# Azure IoTHub - FileUpload - Remove Device Name from BlobName

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

I work on a solution in order to upload images from a LocalFileSystem to Azure Storage.

For the moment we use a TokenSaS and a BlobClient but we would like to avoid to store locally an expiring SaSToken.

In order to do this, we thought about Azure IoTHub, that allows us to replace this process.

```py
def __upload_file_Azure_IoTHub(self,src_path:str,blob_path:str) ->BlobClient:
        if os.path.exists(src_path):
            # We start by creating a blobClient from AzureIoTHub
            storage_info=self.IoTHub_client.get_storage_info_for_blob(blob_path)
            # We create the SAS Url from Client + Token
            sas_url="https://{}/{}/{}{}".format(
                storage_info["hostName"],
                storage_info["containerName"],
                storage_info['blobName'],
                storage_info["sasToken"])
            try:
                with BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url) as blob_client:
                    with open(src_path, "rb") as fp:
                         blob=blob_client.upload_blob(fp,overwrite=True, timeout=self.config.azure_timeout)              
                self.IoTHub_client.notify_blob_upload_status(storage_info["correlationId"], True, 200, "OK: {}".format(blob_path))
                return blob
            except Exception as ex:
                self.IoTHub_client.notify_blob_upload_status(storage_info["correlationId"], False, 403, "Upload Failed")
                raise Exception("AzureUpload_IoTHub")
```

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload.md#device-initialize-a-file-upload

The problem is that when we upload this way, the device name is added as a prefix to the blobName.
It is a problem because it will cause us problems of rectrocompatibility :

- We defined a naming convention in our storage and this behavior will break everything.

Let's imagine :

```
DeviceName = FileWatcherDaemon
BlobPath   = YYYY/MM/DD/MyBlob.whatever
# Then :
BlobName = FileWatcherDaemon/YYYY/MM/DD/MyBlob.whatever
# Instead of :
BlobName = YYYY/MM/DD/MyBlob.whatever
```

I tried replacing the blobName by my blob_path, but it is not working because the generated sasToken is *blobLevel* and not *containerLevel*.

Do you have an idea about how to remove this device name ?

For us it is a problem because we will have many different devices uploading in the same storage. We would like the naming convention to fit with our business needs and not to technical information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any of the other capabilities of Azure IoT Hub besides the fileUpload? Do you need your device to received messages from the Cloud? For your scenario, it may be overkill using IoT Hub just for uploading files.

> For the moment we use a TokenSaS and a BlobClient but we would like to avoid to store locally an expiring SaSToken.

Have a look at [Identity and access management Security Recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/security-recommendations#identity-and-access-management) and consider using Azure Key Vault in your scenario.

> Microsoft recommends using Azure AD to authorize requests to Azure Storage. However, if you must use Shared Key authorization, then secure your account keys with Azure Key Vault. You can retrieve the keys from the key vault at runtime, instead of saving them with your application. For more information about Azure Key Vault, see Azure Key Vault overview.

For more security "Azure Key Vaults may be either software-protected or, with the Azure Key Vault Premium tier, hardware-protected by hardware security modules (HSMs)."